# What is the setup proceedure for an AUConverter for use in an Core Audio AUGraph

Tags: iphone, macos, audio, core-audio

I want to convert from

pcm
44100khz
16bit signed
2 channel
interleaved (packed)

format to

44100khz
floats
2 channel
non-interleaved (2 buffers)

format for use in an AUGraph. I have been messing with it for a few days. whats the best way to set up an AUConverter to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this on the iPhone? I'm pretty sure the converter unit on iPhone [won't handle floats](http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2009/Apr/msg00175.html). To test this, you could try changing your output ASBD to produce int samples and see if it starts working.

Comment: cheers, i've done a bit of investigation and posting to the core audio mailing list and you are correct, there is no audio converter to move int to floats